# GCP - Impersonate Service Account from Local Machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have used AWS in the past. So I might be trying to compare the behavior with GCP. Bear with me and provide the steps to do things in a correct way.

What I did:

- I create a service account in GCP with **storage object viewer** role.
- I also create a key-pair and downloaded the json file in my local.

If I have gcloud/gsutil installed in my local machine, How can I assume/impersonate the service account and work on GCP resources?

Where should i keep the downloaded json file? I already referred to this - https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating

---

I downloaded file as `key.json` and kept in my home directory.
Then I did this.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/key.json"
```

Execute this command

```
gsutil cp dummy.txt gs://my-bucket/
```

Ideally, it should NOT work. but I am able to upload files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the path to your service account in env (when using Google Cloud SDKs):

```bash
#linux
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/path/to/serviceAccountFile.json"

#windows
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\path\to\serviceAccountFile.json"
```

If you don't have the key file, run the following command that'll download the key:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./serviceAccount.json --iam-account=svc_name@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

You can then use `activate-service-account` to use given service account as shown below:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=serviceAccount.json
```

Comment: I do not think it is correct. If I do `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=..` , then will it be taken care? Because I am able to upload files in the bucket even though the role has no permission for that which is not correct.

Comment: @RamPrakash can you share what permissions your service account has?

Comment: The service account has only "storage object viewer" role. It is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RamPrakash I just tested it on my end and I cannot upload images when trying to upload using GCS Node package. Can you provide more details on how you tried it?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with more info. I am really not sure how you do. May be even reading files are not working for you?

Comment: @RamPrakash nvm.. can you use the command in my update answer to activate the given service account?

Comment: Ok..It seems to work. Thanks a lot. 2 simple questions. "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" - does it add any value now? 2nd question - where did you get this from `gcloud auth activate-service-account` ?

Comment: @RamPrakash it's in the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account).  It _"authorizes access to Google Cloud with a service account"_ The env works for the GCloud SDKs... for `gsutil` that won't.