# Generate Google Cloud Signed URL locally by impersonating service account without keys

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I want to use Google Cloud Storage API in NodeJS to generate signed URL

It works inside the Cloud Run environments, but I can't find any way to make it up locally ! I always end up with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot sign data without `client_email`.
```

I know I have to use a Service Account (SA) for this, and it works nicely by impersonating one with the command `gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account SA_EMAIL` or directly `gsutil -i SA_EMAIL signurl -d 10m -u gs://bucket/file`

But it's not working by the code as my ADC credentials doesn't seems to use the impersonation which works in the CLI

I know I can pass in a key file of the service account like that

```
const storage = new Storage({
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'SA_EMAIL',
    private_key: 'path/to/key.json'
  }
});
```

but my organization **doesn't allow** them so I have to find another way for the code to know I'm using the right SA

Comment: Have you [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681578/13130697) ?

Comment: As said, I cannot download SA keys (this is organization policy), else would be easy ! ;)

Comment: Does your org allow your own account to be a `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` for the SA in question?

Comment: Could do yes ! Actually I have `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`, if you have any way with your role let me know I'll try to ask !

Comment: Okay, so good news/bad news. Because you have `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` on the service account, you can use the IAM service's projects.serviceAccount.signBlob function to sign strings (like URLs) on behalf of the service account without having access to the key itself. `gsutil` will handle this for you, but the client library you're using likely will not.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought, gsutil was working but not my code ! Anyway thank you very much ;) Hope the nodejs library will be updated soon !

Answer (score 0):

Your organisation is right, you don't need to use a service account key file, it's a bad thing/idea.

You can do it differently but not sure it works in nodeJS.

Try that `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=xxxx`. This command will create a credential on your local machine based on your own identity and that impersonate the service account.

However, a few libraries accept that new mode (not so new, implemented 6 months ago I guess, but only JAVA supported it. I performed a Golang contribution to allow Golang to support it.) I don't know if NodeJS Google OAuth2 libraries support that authentication mode.

I have 2 other options (in Python) but it seems not supported in Node (I dug into the source code and the feature is not implemented)

if it still does not work, and to continue not to use a service account key file (that is bad) I recommend you to implement the [same feature as I did in Python](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/355) in the client libraries. I don't have the NodeJS skills to do that, and if you can and have time to contribute it would be wonderful!

Comment: We're going somewhere with your command ! But I still have an error, even if it changed: `Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field`. Will try to look to at the Python implementation thanx !

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the Service Account is authorized in the cloud run environment?

My guess is the cloud run environment works because the Service Account is authorized in that environment. On the other hand, locally, you may not have permissions on the service account so you aren't able to impersonate it.

One solution might be to add yourself as a [Service Account User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role) or [Service Account Token Creator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#token-creator-role).

Answer (score -1):

If your org does not allow downloading service account keys, you won't be able to get a service account key onto your local machine.

You've got a few options for local testing (I assume you're doing this for testing?). The simplest, if it's permitted for you, is to create a separate project that is not part of the organization, and get service account keys from there. If it's entirely disconnected from your org's permissions and data, it will hopefully be acceptable to be a bit looser with the credentials.

One alternative, if it works with whatever tools and libraries you're using to sign your URLs, might be to use HMAC authentication. If your organization policy has not blocked HMAC signed requests (although there's a pretty good chance they would have), you could perhaps use HMAC credentials to sign requests instead of service account keys.

Comment: No Brandon. I totally disagree. You can't advocate to perform shadowIT and to overpass the organization security policy, especially coming from a Google Employee!! There are options, but not sure implemented in the NodeJS client library. A better solution is to contribute to that library (and I haven't the skill the that). See my answer.